# How to remove specific element e1 from Observable<MyModel>

Tags: angular, rxjs6

Please advise how to tackle this.
How to remove specific element e1 from Observable myObserv (received after calling getAllProducts API) .

This specific element **e1** is determined based on the response from (subsequent call) getUsedProducts API Observable

```
myObserv.subscribe(next:resp1 => {},error: err =>{},()=>{})
```

Comment: please share some code you are trying inside subscribe, it's still to unclear if you need rxjs or array manipulation help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question completely, but isn't it possible to find the `productId1` by using `.find()`?

Comment: Hey @jobje325 - I am looking for something which is not going to be straightforward, moreover I doubt if its possible. Update it, as trying to make it more readable and understandable

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to combine to http calls? or Array manipulation, share a bit of code and we can help.

forkjoin.subscribe runs only when both finish.

```
        forkJoin(
            this.observable1(),
            this.observable2(Id)
        ).subscribe(([ o1, o2 ]) => {
            //then do some magic with array.filter (or find) based on your needs
            // can update this logic too if you share some code your trying..
        });
```

[running forkjoin example (click run under "Testing forkjoin")](https://lunchandlearnrxjs.firebaseapp.com/test)

if they are dependant on one another you want to use [switchmap to new observable](https://lunchandlearnrxjs.firebaseapp.com/subjectPipeSubscribe)